# Динамическая смена контента при клике на блок с изображением

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Возникла проблема при клике на изображение и появление контента

У меня есть 6 блоков с изображениями, при клике на которые должен снизу появляться контент

К примеру по клику на изображение "+" должен появляться какой-либо контент(как с dropdown menu) и должна происходить смена изображения на "-" и это изображение находится чуть ниже(эффект активного элемента)

У меня смена картинки работает только на первом блоке, все остальные отображаются изначально, хотя должны быть скрыты.

И далее если переключаться между блоками, то должен закрываться другой блок(который активный), но опять же отрабатывает не так как надо.

И как сделать, так, чтобы при первоначальной открытии страницы, именно первый элемент уже был раскрыт?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.js-open-box').click(function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr("data-target");
    if (!jQuery(id).hasClass("active")) {
      //показать блок снизу
      jQuery(this).find('img.change_pic_bottom').hide();
      jQuery(this).find('img.change_pic_top').show();
      jQuery(id).addClass("active");
    } else {
      //убрать блок снизу
      jQuery(id).removeClass("active");
      jQuery(this).find('img.change_pic_bottom').show();
      jQuery(this).find('img.change_pic_top').hide();
    }
  });
  jQuery(this).find('img.change_pic_top').hide();
});
```

```css
.btsc_wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

img.change_pic_top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.picture1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btsc_main_pic {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.btsc_txt {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.picture1 img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  height: 323px;
}

.shadow_pics {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 110px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 105px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 164px;
  height: 240px;
}

.block-of-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block-of-text.active {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive sum_rel_wide_slider_mob">
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box" href="#/" data-target="#box1"><img class="pic1_img change_pic_top" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /><img class="change_pic_bottom" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box" href="#/" data-target="#box2"><img class="pic1_img change_pic" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /><img class="change_pic_bottom" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box" href="#/" data-target="#box3"><img class="pic1_img change_pic" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /><img class="change_pic_bottom" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box" href="#/" data-target="#box4"><img class="pic1_img change_pic" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /><img class="change_pic_bottom" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box" href="#/" data-target="#box5"><img class="pic1_img change_pic" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /><img class="change_pic_bottom" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box" href="#/" data-target="#box6"><img class="pic1_img change_pic" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /><img class="change_pic_bottom" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="btsc_text_af_cat_pic">Выберите категорию</p>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text" id="box1"><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img
    class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics"
    src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512"
  /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img
    class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics"
    src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /></div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text" id="box2"><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /></div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text" id="box3"><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /></div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text" id="box4"><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /></div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text" id="box5"><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /></div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text" id="box6"><img class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://www.staples-3p.com/s7/is/image/Staples/sp46530374_sc7?wid=512&amp;hei=512" /></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Если уверены, что нужно использовать именно `jQuery`, а не `$`, это всё можно обернуть в общую функцию)

"Чтобы первый элемент изначально был раскрыт" — не добавлять класс "hidden" на первый элемент)

При условии, что все плюс-минусы будут являться разными картинками:

```js
(function($){

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.js-open-box').on('click', function(){
    $('.plus').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.minus').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.plus').addClass('hidden')
    $(this).find('.minus').removeClass('hidden');
    
    $('.js-block-of-text').hide();
    var index = $('.js-open-box').index( $(this) );
    $('.js-block-of-text').eq(index).show();
  });
  
});

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.plus, .minus {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.picture1, .js-open-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="responsive sum_rel_wide_slider_mob">
  <div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box" href="#/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" class="plus hidden"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" class="minus"></a></div>
  <div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box" href="#/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" class="plus"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" class="minus hidden"></a></div>
  <div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box" href="#/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" class="plus"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" class="minus hidden"></a></div>
  <div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box" href="#/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" class="plus"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" class="minus hidden"></a></div>
  <div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box" href="#/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" class="plus"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" class="minus hidden"></a></div>
  <div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box" href="#/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" class="plus"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" class="minus hidden"></a></div>
</div>
<p class="btsc_text_af_cat_pic">Выберите категорию</p>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text">1111</div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text hidden">2222</div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text hidden">3333</div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text hidden">4444</div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text hidden">5555</div>
<div class="js-block-of-text block-of-text hidden">6666</div>
```

Comment: я просто спросить хотел , а вот `$(function ($){ .... })` и `$(document).ready(function ($){ ... })` это не одно и тоже ?

Comment: @MaximLensky А я и не знал. Оказывается, да))

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ) Дело в том, что изображения плюс и минус у меня разные) к примеру, первый блок одна картинка, второй блок другая, т.е они не однотипные

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да я не прикалываюсь ...мне на самом деле интересно - это одно и тоже или нет ?

Comment: @MaximLensky а я тоже... Правда не знал. Поискал - выяснилось, что одно и то же)

Comment: @Dmitriy Andreevich *отредактировано*

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Спасибо вам, все сработало, а не подскажите как добавить анимацию открытия? это лучше через js сделать?(.click animate) т.к. с transition не получается

Comment: @Dmitriy Andreevich А у меня всё плохо с анимациями) Вместо show / hide можно использовать fadeOut() / fadeIn() в комбинации с .delay() ... или slideUp() / slideDown() P.s. transition не работает с переключениями display: none / block, т.к. это всего два состояния. Такие анимации основаны на изменении прозрачности opacity от 1 до 0 - и уже последующим display: none;

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME У меня такая проблема из-за display:none; у меня эти блоки в слайдере slick, и стили из слайдера переписывают стиль hidden:display:none; можно как-то сделать без display:none? Пробовал прописать !important, но поведение некорректно, отображается контент только первого блока, остальные не показываются

Comment: @DmitriyAndreevich !important не работает из-за hide / show. Можно добавить тот же important и заменить их на addClass / removeClass('hidden'). Или, вообще убрать этот класс, и везде вместо addClass, записать в виде `$('.plus').css('display', 'inline-block'); $('.minus').css('display', 'none');` и т.п. Встроенные style="..." перебивают стили от классов.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
  jQuery('.js-open-box').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('.plus').css('display', 'inline-block');
    jQuery('.minus').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery(this).find('.plus').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery(this).find('.minus').css('display', 'inline-block');    
    jQuery('.js-block-of-text').hide();
    var index = jQuery('.js-open-box').index( jQuery(this) );
    jQuery('.js-block-of-text').eq(index).show();
  });
  
}); но если прописать у minus{display:none}, то стили слика не переписываются